# Two PHP array values appear same but show different

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
$userPass = $invItem['cfields'][8]['pw']; //Value provided from a form
$sqlPass = $row['user_pass'];     //Value from SQL
echo "Pass: <pre>", $userPass, "</pre><br />";
echo "SQL Pass: <pre>", $sqlPass, "</pre><br />";
```

userPass is a value from a login form, this is a nested array. There are multiple arrays of different sizes nested within each other. sqlPass is the result of an SQL query containing a stored password I'm trying to authenticate against.

The scenario I'm testing uses a password with symbols, "p@$S" for example.

Without the htmlspecialchars(), the two passwords appear to be the same, but with the htmlspecialchars() they look like the following:

```
Pass: p@&#036;S
SQLPass: p@$S
```

What can I do to get these two values from different strings to compare properly?

Comment: Loop through all the characters in each string and print their ascii code. Check the length of each string.

Answer (score 0):

Your output looks the same to me... but then I am getting old :)

Your line `$sqlPass = htmlspecialchars('trim', $row['user_pass']);` is wrong, so `$sqlPass` has the wrong value after using the `htmlspecialchars`. As you are pulling it from the DB anyway there should be no need to reuse [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) in this case. The problem with your line is it's using a string of 'trim', and interpreting the second variable as an int.

Comment: That was a copy and paste error, the "'trim', " is not really there. The two arrays still appear the same, but will not compare and show up differently when using htmlspecialchars() or MD5().

Comment: Ok then, using the same code to echo the two vars, add a <pre></pre> block around the echo's. That way you will be able to see the exact strings, and hopefully spot what's going wrong where. But still, you should probably nor be using htmlspecialchars again on the string you retrieved from the database, assuming you used it before storing the password in the database.

Comment: ps You can edit your question to fix the copy and paste error.

Comment: Changed the echos to: echo "Pass: <pre>", $userPass, "</pre><br />";
  echo "SQL Pass: <pre>", $sqlPass, "</pre><br />"; and there's no visible difference between the two lines without the htmlspecialchars(). But they still will not compare.

Comment: `echo "<pre>".$sqlPass."</pre>";`

Comment: Ok, I see you updated again. At least now you can see the two values are different. It looks like the results you have posted show $userPass using htmlspecialchars. Can you post the line where you populate `$invItem['cfields'][8]['pw'];`? eg `$invItem['cfields'][8]['pw']=$_GET['pass'];`

Comment: You are double applying the htmlspecialchars() somehow. When your PHP script sends the output to your browser it uses a "Content-type: text/html" header therefore you "lose" one encoding because your browser converts the entities to symbols (if there are some) or it prints the symbols directly if they are not encoded. Try right click and "View source" to see what I mean :-)

Comment: The `$invItem['cfields'][8]['pw'];` is populated by an Invision Power Board Nexus app which is zend encoded so I can't show you the actual code, all I know is that's how I reference the data I need.

Comment: Ok then, on the encoded variable, ie $userPass, use `<?php $userPass=htmlspecialchars_decode($invItem['cfields'][8]['pw']);?>`. That should sort you out.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the help everyone provided in pointing me toward a solution. I ended up resolving this issue by using `$userPass = html_entity_decode($invItem['cfields'][8]['pw'])`.